# MySQL Query Two Tables and Max Timestamp

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I have two tables that look something like this:

TABLE_conversations:

```
+-----------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+--------+
| CONVERSATION_ID | QUEUE_ID | CONTACT_NUMBER | CONTACT_ID | DATE_CREATED        | STATUS |
+-----------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+--------+
|               1 |        1 | 15551112222    |    9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:28:24 | ACTIVE |
|               2 |        1 | 15553334444    |    9000002 | 2014-09-12 00:32:08 | ACTIVE |
+-----------------+----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+--------+
```

TABLE_messages:

```
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| MESSAGE_ID | CONVERSATION_ID | FROM_NUMBER | TO_NUMBER   | DIRECTION | SENDER  | TIMESTAMP          | VIEWED | MESSAGE                                                                                                         | STATUS |
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
|          1 |               1 | 15551112222 | 17021112222 | IN        | 9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:30:11 |      1 | Hello!  Is this working?                                                                     | ACTIVE |
|          2 |               1 | 17021112222 | 15551112222 | OUT       | 8000001 | 2014-09-12 00:31:05 |      1 | Good evening!  Of course!  | ACTIVE |
|          3 |               1 | 15551112222 | 17021112222 | IN        | 9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:31:27 |      1 | Perfect.  Thank you!                                                                                            | ACTIVE |
|          4 |               1 | 17021112222 | 15553334444 | OUT       | 8000002 | 2014-09-12 00:32:52 |      1 | Ticket 11251 is ready for pickup.                                                                         | ACTIVE |
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
```

I'm trying to run a query to select the CONVERSATION_ID, CONTACT_NUMBER, CONTACT_ID and most recent TIMESTAMP and grouping by phone number:

```
SELECT TABLE_conversations.CONVERSATION_ID, TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_NUMBER,
       TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_ID, MAX(TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP) 
FROM TABLE_conversations, TABLE_messages 
WHERE TABLE_conversations.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
AND TABLE_messages.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
GROUP BY CONTACT_NUMBER 
ORDER BY TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP;
```

The output I'm getting is below:

```
+-----------------+----------------+------------+-------------------------------+
| CONVERSATION_ID | CONTACT_NUMBER | CONTACT_ID | MAX(TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP) |
+-----------------+----------------+------------+-------------------------------+
|               1 | 15551112222    |    9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:32:52           |
|               2 | 15553334444    |    9000002 | 2014-09-12 00:32:52           |
+-----------------+----------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

I'm getting the same TIMESTAMP for both.  The result I want is 2014-09-12 00:31:27 for 15551112222 and 2014-09-12 00:32:52 for 15553334444.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing join conditions between the tables, so you're getting a full cross-product. So every conversation is being joined with every message, not just the messages from that conversation.

```
SELECT TABLE_conversations.CONVERSATION_ID, TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_NUMBER,
       TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_ID, MAX(TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP) 
FROM TABLE_conversations
JOIN TABLE_messages ON TABLE_conversations.conversation_id = TABLE_messages.conversation_id
WHERE TABLE_conversations.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
AND TABLE_messages.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
GROUP BY CONTACT_NUMBER 
ORDER BY TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  When I run this query, I'm only getting one record when there should be two.  I also get the timestamp associated with another record:  `     1 | 15551112222    |    9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:32:52`

Comment: Disregard my comment - your query works perfectly!  I had used conversation ID 1 for everything which is why I was only getting one record.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your sql cross join all rows from two tables, so the max timestamp for any group is the same.

```
SELECT TABLE_conversations.CONVERSATION_ID, 
       TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_NUMBER, 
       TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_ID, 
       MAX(TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP) 
FROM TABLE_conversations
JOIN TABLE_messages 
ON TABLE_conversations.CONVERSATION_ID = TABLE_messages.CONVERSATION_ID 
WHERE TABLE_conversations.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
      AND TABLE_messages.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
GROUP BY CONTACT_NUMBER
```

Suggest you to get rid of the group by and aggregation function to see what's different between full cross join and inner join. Such as:

```
SELECT TABLE_conversations.CONVERSATION_ID, 
       TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_NUMBER, 
       TABLE_conversations.CONTACT_ID, 
       TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP
FROM TABLE_conversations
JOIN TABLE_messages 
ON TABLE_conversations.CONVERSATION_ID = TABLE_messages.CONVERSATION_ID 
--without on clause above, comes to the full cross join
WHERE TABLE_conversations.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
      AND TABLE_messages.STATUS='ACTIVE' 
ORDER BY TABLE_messages.TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.  This doesn't appear to be working.  I receive four records (when I should get two) and some with the wrong phone number:                1 | 15551112222    |    9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:30:11 |
|               1 | 15551112222    |    9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:31:05 |
|               1 | 15551112222    |    9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:31:27 |
|               1 | 15551112222    |    9000001 | 2014-09-12 00:32:52

Comment: my bad. get rid of the order by clause.